# Why can't I search through the dictionary I created (Python)?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

In this program I am making a dictionary from a plain text file, basically I count the amount a word occurs in a document, the word becomes the key and the amount of time it occurs is the value. I can create the dictionary but then I cannot search through the dictionary. Here is my updated code with your guys' input. I really appreciate the help.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import operator
def readFile(fileHandle):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    with open(fileHandle, "r") as myfile:
        for currline in myfile: 
            for word in currline.split():
                d[word] +=1
    return d

def reverseLookup(dictionary, value):
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        if dictionary[key] == value:
            return key
    return None

afile = raw_input ("What is the absolute file path: ")
print readFile (afile)

choice = raw_input ("Would you like to (1) Query Word Count (2) Print top words to a new document     (3) Exit: ") 
if (choice == "1"):
    query = raw_input ("What word would like to look up? ")
    print reverseLookup(readFile(afile), query)
if (choice == "2"):
    f = open("new.txt", "a")
    d = dict(int)
    for w in text.split():
        d[w] += 1
    f.write(d)
    file.close (f)
if (choice == "3"):
    print "The EXIT has HAPPENED"
else:
    print "Error"
```

Comment: So... what's the problem again?

Comment: What is the line `d =` supposed to do?

Comment: your `reverseLookup` function seems to look for the first word with `v` occurrences, is that what you want ? Also, you shouldn't use the keyword `dict`

Comment: @Bryan: You can simply paste the code as-is, then select all of it and press Ctrl-K. Then it will be indented correctly.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker took care of it

Comment: @Bryan: The "took care of it " isn't helpful.  Please remove it.  Please explain what the error is with your code -- as posted.  After all the revisions, it's hard to understand the comments or the answers.

Comment: @Bryan: What exactly is that "choice 2" supposed to do?

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is very complicated (and syntactically wrong, at least in your posted code sample).

Also, you're rebinding the built-in name `dict` which is problematic, too.

Furthermore, this functionality is already built-in in Python:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def readFile(fileHandle):
    d = defaultdict(int)  # Access to undefined keys creates a entry with value 0
    with open(fileHandle, "r") as myfile:   # File will automatically be closed
        for currline in myfile:             # Loop through file line-by-line
            for word in currline.strip().split(): # Loop through words w/o CRLF
                d[word] +=1                 # Increase word counter
    return d
```

As for your `reverseLookup` function, see ypercube's answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new at this and I want to understand how this works. I am having trouble reading your code when it is all meshed together like that

Comment: You're right, that code needed some comments. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 3):

Your code returns after it looks in the first (key,value) pair. You have to search the whole dictionary before returning that the value has not been found.

```
def reverseLookup(dictionary, value):
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        if dictionary[key] == value:
            return key
    return None
```

You should also not return `"error"` as it can be a word and thus a key in your dictionary!

Comment: Don't use the dict keyword, that's a very bad idea

Comment: So right now you are instantiating a __blank__ dictionary each time you call `reverseLookup`

Comment: Why create a new variable `d`?  Why not simply use `def reverseLookup(d, v):` and drop the second line?

Comment: every time I try to search the dictionary with user input it always comes up as d is not defined

Comment: when I call on the function, what would "dictionary" be replaced with?

Comment: sorry, def reverseLookup(:dictionary:, value): 


that dictionary

Comment: @Bryan: The name your dictionary has in that part of the code, where you call the function. Post the part that calls the function by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how you're intending to *use* this `reverseLookup()` function, you might find your code much happier if you employ *two* dictionaries: build the first dictionary as you already do, and then build a *second* dictionary that contains mappings between the number of occurrences and the words that occurred that many times. Then your `reverseLookup()` wouldn't need to perform the `for k in d.keys()` loop on *every single lookup*. That loop would only happen once, and every single lookup after that would run significantly faster.

I've cobbled together (but not tested) some code that shows what I'm talking about. I stole Tim's `readFile()` routine, because I like the look of it more :) but took his nice function-local dictionary `d` and moved it to global, just to keep the functions short and sweet. In a 'real project', I'd probably wrap the whole thing in a class to allow arbitrary number of dictionaries at run time and provide reasonable encapsulation. This is just demo code. :)

```
import operator
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
numbers_dict = {}

def readFile(fileHandle):
    with open(fileHandle, "r") as myfile:
        for currline in myfile:
            for word in currline.split():
                d[word] +=1
    return d


def prepareReverse():
    for (k,v) in d.items():
        old_list = numbers_dict.get(v, [])
        new_list = old_list << k
        numbers_dict[v]=new_list

def reverseLookup(v):
    numbers_dict[v]
```

If you intend on making two or more lookups, this code will trade memory for execution speed. You only iterate through the dictionary once (iteration over all elements is not a dict's strong point), but at the cost of duplicate data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The search is not working because you have a dictionary mapping a word to its count, so getting the number of occurrences for a 'word' should be just `dictionary[word]`. You don't really need the `reveseLookup()`, there is already a `.get(key, default_value)` method in dict: `dictionary.get(value, None)`